# jQuery UI multiple selectable tooltips are collapsing

Tags: jquery-ui, tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

I'm new to jQuery UI.

I'm trying to create a **selectable** jQuery UI tooltip. The tooltip is associated with the links on a page.

When the link is surrounded by just text, it works fine. But when there are few links next to each other, the functionality overlaps and tooltips don't show smoothly anymore.

you can find the code on http://jsfiddle.net/zumot/Hc3FK/2/

Below the JavaScript code

```
$("[title][data-scan]").bind("mouseleave", function (event) {
event.stopImmediatePropagation();
var fixed = setTimeout('$("[title][data-scan]").tooltip("close")', 100);
$(".ui-tooltip").click(function () {
    alert("I am clickable");
    return false;
});
$(".ui-tooltip").hover(
function () {
    clearTimeout(fixed);
},
function () {
    $("[title][data-scan]").tooltip("close");
});}).tooltip({
items: "img, [data-scan], [title]",
content: function () {
    var element = $(this);
    if (element.is("[data-scan]")) {
        var text = element.attr("href");
        return "<a href='http://www.google.com'>You are trying to open a tooltip  <span>" + text + "</span></a>";
    }
    if (element.is("[title]")) {
        return element.attr("title");
    }
    if (element.is("img")) {
        return element.attr("alt");
    }
},
position: {
    my: "right center",
    at: "left center",
    delay: 200,
    using: function (position, feedback) {
        $(this).css(position);
        $("<div>")
        .addClass(feedback.vertical)
            .addClass(feedback.horizontal)
            .appendTo(this);
    }
}});
```

Answer (score 1):

My attempt to fix the issue was by making the variable **`fixed`** global (to make it accessible by other jQuery UI properties), and on **`Open`** event, hide any other previously opened tooltips and clear the timeout id saved in `fixed` variable.

---

You can find the solution here http://jsfiddle.net/zumot/dVGWB/ 
, though to see the code working properly, you'll have to run it directly on your browser.

---

Here's the snapshort of the fixed code.

```
    // Make the timeout id variable global
    var fixed = 0;

$("[title][data-scan]").tooltip({
    items: "img, [data-scan], [title]",
    content: function () {
        var element = $(this);
        if (element.is("[data-scan]")) {
            var text = element.attr("href");
            return "<a href='http://www.google.com'>You are trying to open a tooltip  <span>" + text + "</span></a>";
        }
        if (element.is("[title]")) {
            return element.attr("title");
        }
        if (element.is("img")) {
            return element.attr("alt");
        }
    },
    open: function (event, ui) {
        // When opening a new div, hide any previously opened tooltips first.
        $(".ui-tooltip:not([id=" + ui.tooltip[0].id + "])").hide();
        // clear timeout as well if there's any.
        if (tf > 0) {
            clearTimeout(tf)
        };
    },
    position: {
        my: "right center",
        at: "left center",
        delay: 200,
        using: function (position, feedback) {
            $(this).css(position);
            $("<div>")
                .addClass(feedback.vertical)
                .addClass(feedback.horizontal)
                .appendTo(this);
        }
    }
}).bind("mouseleave", function (event) {
    // stop defeulat behaviour
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    fixed = setTimeout('$("[title][data-scan]").tooltip("close")', 100);
    $(".ui-tooltip").hover(

    function () {
        clearTimeout(tf);
    }, function () {
        $("[title][data-scan]").tooltip("close");
    })
});
```